# Logical replication fails at failover because of sequence

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, logical-replication, postgres-12

I have two servers A and B, server A is the publisher for table with primary key sequence. Before i switch to server B, I update the sequence in server B to be same as server A. Then I do the failover and make server B the publisher and server A the subscriber, the insertion works perfectly on server B, but replication fails on server A, although they both have the same value for:

```
SELECT last_value FROM orders_id_seq
```

The script to update the sequence on the new publisher:

```
import psycopg2

def check_and_move_sequence(table, source_conn, target_conn):
    with source_conn.cursor() as source_cursor:
        # Check if a sequence exists for the table
        source_cursor.execute(f"SELECT column_name, column_default FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '{table}' AND column_default LIKE 'nextval%'")
        sequence_data = source_cursor.fetchone()
        
        if sequence_data:
            sequence_column, sequence_name = sequence_data
            sequence_name = sequence_name.split("'")[1]
            # Get the maximum value of the primary key column in the table
            source_cursor.execute(f"SELECT MAX({sequence_column}) FROM {table}")
            max_val = source_cursor.fetchone()[0]
            
            # Generate SQL script to set sequence value
            set_sequence_sql = f"SELECT setval('{sequence_name}', {max_val});"
            
            # Execute the SQL script on the target connection
            with target_conn.cursor() as target_cursor:
                target_cursor.execute(set_sequence_sql)
                target_conn.commit()
```

Comment: "Replication fails": what are the error messages in the log?

Comment: 2023-08-31 16:22:53.858 UTC [138107] LOG:  logical replication table synchronization worker for subscription "orders_subscription", table "orders" has started
2023-08-31 16:22:53.978 UTC [138107] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "orders_pkey"
2023-08-31 16:22:53.978 UTC [138107] DETAIL:  Key (id)=(10) already exists.
2023-08-31 16:22:53.978 UTC [138107] CONTEXT:  COPY orders, line 1
2023-08-31 16:22:53.982 UTC [108540] LOG:  background worker "logical replication worker" (PID 138107) exited with exit code 1

Comment: The inserting on the new publisher works fine, but still data are not replicated correctly unless I delete all the records from the table on the new subscriber. Then everything works fine.

Comment: If the data in the tables differ, that cannot work. This as expected.